# Resource re-package Failed

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

Can't Build n Run Unity3d make Apk

> Resource re-package Failed!
>   package -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/Program Files/android-sdk-windows/platforms/android-10\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_
>
> AndroidManifest.xml:13: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen').
>   AndroidManifest.xml:19: error: Error: 
>   AndroidManifest.xml:21: error: Error: 
>   AndroidManifest.xml:25: error: Error:
>
> UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
>   PostProcessAndroidPlayer:PostProcess(BuildTarget, String, String, String, String, String, String, BuildOptions)
>   (at C:/BuildAgent/work/842f9557127e852/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostProcessAndroidPlayer.cs:210)
>   UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

Please Help

Answer (score 1):

For me the fix was relatively simple: after reading the release notes here I found that "Editor requires at least API level 14 to build Android applications." So all I had to do was to update my installed software.
(these steps may be slightly different for Windows)
Open Eclipse.
Click 'Help' -> 'Check for updates'
(I had to do this step first because my Android SDK manager wasn't working)
then open the Android SDK manager and download the latest SDK and Tools.

And that's it.